# How to treat buffer object from pybind11 as NumPy ndarray with minimal syntax?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, numpy-ndarray, pybind11

Note: More background and detail is provided before the question is repeated following the code block.

### Big Picture

I’m building a library for use in both C++ and Python. The implementation is in C++, with a thin wrapper for users to be able to build projects in Python using this library with minimal impact on performance. The option to use an API in both languages is a hard requirement.

Ultimately, I want to make things simple (in terms of how much users need to type on their keyboard to do something that will come up frequently) for users of this library. This question concerns the Python API.

### A little deeper now...

I’m working on a project where I have a class written in C++, and I’m exposing it to Python. I’m using pybind11 to do this. I want to treat my class as a NumPy ndarray without creating a copy.

This will allow users of the Python API to work entirely within Python, which is a hard requirement of this project. The use of numpy without making copies of the underlying data is also a hard requirement.

### Illustrative Example

Let’s say I’ve defined a class `Foo` in C++ and followed the instructions on pybind11 to allow for the following (actually, I have done this, except the part where it says, “I want this...”):

```py
from mymodule import Foo
import NumPy as np

# assume arg1 and arg2 are defined
f = Foo(arg1)
g =Foo(arg2)
h = Foo() # Foo has multiple constructors

# I want this...
h[:] = f + g

# ...to be equivalent to this (this is the part I’ve done successfully):
H = np.array(h, copy=False)
H[:] = np.array(f, copy=False) + np.array(g, copy=False)
```

### The Question

Is there a way to do what I described in the code block above?

### This is not an XY Problem

The goal is to force the user to type less, given the requirement that data be accessible via numpy.ndarray objects without making copies of the underlying data. Ideally, that means treating the objects as if they are already numpy.ndarray objects without any additional function calls or operations.

### Explored so far...

I’m aware that this asking a lot of Python because I’m operating on a different type from what f and g are — they don’t even inherit from numpy.ndarray.

I’ve tried looking into class decorators. I wonder if could import Foo, and then decorate it so that `f=Foo()` is equivalent to `f=np.array(Foo(), copy=False)`, where Foo is implemented in C++. I’m not sure how decorators work, despite RTFM, if this is the right track, or if I’m close to proving this is impossible.